# Requested scopes not allowed

Tags: java, google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to fetch a user from [Google Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) with the following request:

```
Collection<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user");
URL url = getClass().getResource("privatekey.p12");
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setJsonFactory(request.getJsonFactory())
    .setServiceAccountId("foobar.com")
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
    .setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
    .setServiceAccountUser("foo@bar.com")
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(url.getPath())).build();
Directory dir = new Directory.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), request.getJsonFactory(), credential)
    .setApplicationName(request.getApplicationName())
    .build();
```

But I'm getting the following error from the API:

```
Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied",
  "error_description" : "Requested scopes not allowed: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
}
```

I've checked the scopes are correct, anyone know what's the problem here?

Comment: foobar.com and foo@bar.com seem shady.

Comment: Ye, they're censored. API gives different response if their represented values are invalid, so they should be ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh! I removed the old service account and created a new one. After that things started to roll. Guessing I had a wrong p12 file etc. Can finally breathe again, phew.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one scope or the other. If you only need read access, use the readonly scope. If you need read/write access to users, use the other.

Also, ensure that you've granted the service account's client_id access to these scopes in the Admin's control panel (admin.google.com) and that your ServiceAccountUser is a super admin in the domain.

Comment: In admin console I added client ID(from the app oauth panel) and the scopes. Also ServiceAccountUser is marked as owner in admin console. Still getting same error

Comment: owner in admin console? You mean a Google Apps super admin user?

Comment: Ye sry, I meant super admin. Looked up some other instructions but strangely getting nowhere. With APIs explorer user fetch works ok